# Modules in java.util (collection)

Tags: java, oop

As per JLS, there is no jargon as module.

But as per the classroom [training](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/lec/18.pdf), I learnt that, amidst Software development, a large programming project is divided into multiple modules, the developer uses this term *module* as,

> *Module* is a collection of methods that provide some functionality through a single (hopefully elegant) interface.
>
> A module can be made up of several classes, or a class could be made up of several modules.
>
> A java `package` may contain one module or many.
>
> The main difference between a *module* and a `class` is this:
>
> - A *module* is organized around the *functionality* it provides.
> - A java `class` is organized around a *DataStorageUnit* (An object is a repository of data.)

As per above definitions, I understood that modules are as shown below.

### [image]

Here each module is made of several classes and single interface. For example, *Module 2* has several classes, `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, `TreeSet`. *Module 2* has a single interface `Set`.

*Module 2* is organised around the functionality of set operations.

`java.util` package has 4 modules, as per above diagram.

Segregation in terms of module help multiple programmers develop different modules parallely amidst software developemnt, with obeyed interface on each module.

Is my understanding correct about *module* and it's interface?

If yes, In general, Is software project segregated based on such *modules* before implementation?

Comment: Where are you getting that definition from?

Comment: @overexchange: Easy!  A module is some random term that some random computer science course decided meant something but doesn't actually have any generally agreed meaning.

Comment: AFAIK, technically nothing like module exist in collection framework, but for simpler breakdown of collection framework you (or instructor) broke down collection framework in module.
So, what basically you are doing is segregating the utilities (Map, Queue etc) on the basis of functionalitiies they provide,

Comment: @overexchange This segregation is OK, if it clears the picture of collection framework to you. 

But IMHO, this definition of module may not fit in every case. So, with scenario you may need to tinker your module definition.

Answer (score 2):

There is no formal concept of a 'Module' in java.util ( or java jdk in general ). The concept of a single interface being used for multiple implementations is much more generic , though its most clearly visible in java.util package. If it ( the 'module' way of thinking ) helps you to mentally organize functionality, then you are free to do so and TBH its not wrong either, just don't look for formalizations in jdk.

Answer (score 1):

Java 9 introduces the modules concept into Java (project Jigsaw). According to this concept there's one big module called `java.base` which contains `java.util`, `java.io`, `java.lang`, `java.math` and many other packages, but does not include SQL, XML, Swing, AWT, Java Beans and so on. You can take a look on [codebase](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/77228d1afabb/src/java.base/share/classes) to see what's included in `java.base`.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-split-into-modules more on modules

Comment: @overexchange, it's about NetBeans modules which is somewhat special thing and non-applicable to the JDK core.